# Why ISSET($_GET['variable'] is empty despite transmission?

Tags: php, get, isset

I am just confused when I try the following "file.php?variable=test":

```
<?php
$variable = "";
if(!ISSET($_GET['variable'])) {
    echo "no variable is set";
} else {
    echo "variable is $variable";
}
```

It doesn't echo "test".

But with `var_dump($_GET);` it shows:

array(1) { ["variable"]=> string(4) "test" }

So the $_GET istn't empty right?

Do I really need to add `$variable = $_GET['variable'];` in the else part so that "test" is displayed? And as long as I don't do that, the variable is just TRUE?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Well, you could just use `echo "variable is ".$_GET['variable'];`

Comment: `Do I really need to add $variable = $_GET['variable'];`...yes of course you do. Variables don't magically assign themselves. PHP doesn't know you want to do that assignment unless you specifically tell it to. Why do you expect/imagine that you would be able to get away with not doing it? As the comment above says, you could get away with it by simply echoing the $_GET variable directly, instead, thus avoiding needing an extra variable. But that's not the same as failing to assign a variable which you then try to use later.

Comment: `And as long as I don't do that, the variable is just TRUE?`...no, `$variable` will have the value `""` (an empty string) because that's what you gave it. An empty string is a different value than `true` (although it is truthy in certain situations (you can look up "truthy PHP" if you don't know what I mean)).

Comment: Ok, I understand, I didn't see the forest for the trees. Sorry!